# Redux action working only with bindActionCreators

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have simple React & Redux app and I have strange issue.
Here the main files of my project:

Home.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as productActions from "../../actions/product";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Home extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.actions.getProducts();
    }

    render() {
        const { products, actions } = this.props;
        const cart = products.filter(product => product.addToCart);

        return (
            <div className="home mt-5">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">Products</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    {products.map(product => (
                        <div key={product.id} className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div
                                className="view_details"
                                onClick={() => actions.addToCart(product)}
                            >
                                {product.name}{" "}
                                <u>{product.addToCart ? "Remove" : "Add to Cart"}</u>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-4">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">Cart:</h2>
                        {cart.map(product => (
                            <div key={product.id}>{product.name}</div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        products: state.product.products
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch)
    })
)(Home);
```

actions/product.js file:

```
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS_DATA, ADD_TO_CART } from "../types/products";

export const getProducts = () => dispatch =>
    fetch(`data.json`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_DATA,
                payload: response.products
            });
        });

export const addToCart = product => ({
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    product
});
```

reducers/productReducer.js file:

```
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS_DATA, ADD_TO_CART } from "../types/products";

const initialState = {
    products: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload.map(product => ({
                    ...product,
                    addToCart: false
                }))
            };
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: state.products.map(product =>
                    product.id === action.product.id
                        ? { ...product, addToCart: !product.addToCart }
                        : product
                )
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There are more files that is not neccesry to share with you here.
With the code above everything is working as expected, the problem is when I don't use the bindActionCreators method.
With the following Home.js file (with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps) only the getProducts action is working well but the addToCart action give me the following error: "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" in this file: reducers/productReducer.js:20

Home.js file with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getProducts, addToCart } from "../../actions/product";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Home extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.actions.getProducts();
    }

    render() {
        const { products, actions } = this.props;
        const cart = products.filter(product => product.addToCart);

        return (
            <div className="home mt-5">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">Products</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    {products.map(product => (
                        <div key={product.id} className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div
                                className="view_details"
                                onClick={() => actions.addToCart(product)}
                            >
                                {product.name}{" "}
                                <u>{product.addToCart ? "Remove" : "Add to Cart"}</u>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-4">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">Cart:</h2>
                        {cart.map(product => (
                            <div key={product.id}>{product.name}</div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        products: state.product.products
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: {
            getProducts: () => dispatch(getProducts()),
            addToCart: () => dispatch(addToCart())
        }
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Someone can tell me why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your error

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: {
            getProducts: () => dispatch(getProducts()),
            addToCart: () => dispatch(addToCart())
        }
    };
};
```

`addToCart` accepts 1 argument, `product`. But when you're not using `bindActionCreators`, `addToCart` has no arguments. You're dispatching `addToCart{}` without any arguments. `products === undefined` and you have error.

To solve, add argument to `addToCart`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: {
            getProducts: () => dispatch(getProducts()),
            addToCart: (product) => dispatch(addToCart(product))
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!
One more question please, in the actions file there are two functions.
Inside the getProducts function there is usage of dispatch function, in the addToCart not, why? every action should use the dispatch function? when I need to use the dispatch function inside action?
Thank you @Fyodor

Comment: `getProducts` is an [async action creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#async-action-creators). This is a function returning another function. This returned function (which accepts `dispatch` as argument), will be called by thunk middleware. `addToCart` is just a function which will return an action (plain object). It is a [synchronous action creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#synchronous-action-creators) and doesn't require. `dispatch`

And please don't forget to accept answer :-)